# how to parse an array Json with Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

I recived data by ajax

```
<?
 $locations[] = array(
'Name'=>$name,
'Latitude'=>$lat,
'Longitude'=>$long};
print_r(json_encode($locations));
?>
```

Here I have error, becasu it doesn't show anything when I tried with alert(data) and it work and show the array json that is below

```
success:function(data) {
  var dat =$.parseJSON(data);
   $("#pru").html(dat.Name); //here it doesn't show anything if I put alert(data) it show me all the array json
}
```

the array json content, the next array:

```
[{"Name":"Jayme jayden","Latitude":"36.712005","Longitude":"-4.43825"},
{"Name":"Jhonny","Latitude":"36.728744","Longitude":"-4.443822"},
{"Name":"Jessica Lynn","Latitude":"36.7418","Longitude":"-4.4333 "}]
```

Comment: `$("#pru").html(resp[0].Name);` Edit: + read Joseph's answer

Comment: It is already parsed, you just have to access it properly.

Comment: @Peter Szymkowski I already changed $("#pru").html(dat[0].Name) and it doesn't work

Comment: Do you know what the brackets in `$locations[] =` do?

Comment: @FelixKling - How? Unless the server is sending valid JSON headers (which I doubt) or the data type is set to JSON (which the OP has not shown), how would it already be parsed?

Comment: @Joseph: No I mean it looks like the OP already parsed the JSON (`$.parseJSON`), so the problem is not about parsing it but rather how to properly access the result. That's of course under the assumption that the JSON was valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `print_r` to send JSON. Just do a regular `echo`:

```
$locations = array(
    'Name' => $name,
    'Latitude' => $lat,
    'Longitude' => $long
);

echo json_encode($locations);
```

You also have a syntax error in your code (the closing brace for the array), and I think you're unintentionally creating a multi-dimensional array. Use the code above, and it *should* work.

Comment: Technically right but it does not make a difference, since json_encode always returns a string and print_r on strings just behaves like print/echo.

Comment: @fab - True, which is why I also point out 2 other problems in the code.

Comment: Yes, after you edited it, the answer is great